# Symfony2 - doctrine connection configuration in bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have project which uses my additional bundle. This bundle connects to other database and I need configuration for another database.

I want to have this connections in 2 config files.

main config:

```
# ROOT/app/config/config.yml:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

bundle config:

```
# src/SecondBundle/Resources/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            secondBundle:
                driver:   "%secondBundle.database_driver%"
                host:     "%secondBundle.database_host%"
                port:     "%secondBundle.database_port%"
                dbname:   "%secondBundle.database_name%"
                user:     "%secondBundle.database_user%"
                password: "%secondBundle.database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

Bundle Extension file:

```
class SecondBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('config.yml');
    }
}
```

In my opinion everything looks OK, but when I'm trying to run this I have communicate:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine"

Comment: It seems like the configuration for your bundle is being read and run prior to the configuration of Doctrine. I'd suggest you to have a look at [CompilerPasses](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to set up your container and configuration priorities accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your extra config to the imports in your `app/config/config.yml` so that it is merged into the full `config`.

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: '@SecondBundle/Resources/config/config.yml' }
```

Updated with quotes due to the fact that `` a non-quoted string cannot start with @ or ` (reserved) nor with a scalar indicator (| or >) `` since version 3.0.

Comment: ok for importing the config, but how to use the second database without a second entity manager ?

Comment: The entity manager has nothing to do with the error shown. The error is due to the fact that the `DoctrineBundle` has not been loaded when the config file is being loaded in the extension. As an entity manager is not mentioned in the question at all it may mean that the connection is used directly as opposed to with an entity manager at all.

Comment: I see you point, but I think oriented the response with the doctrine cookbook is a good way to help him with is two databases

Comment: Entity manager is another thing. I'm putting second argument to `getRepository` function in `\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` doctrine class.

Comment: @Nicolas, I didn't find that necessary as the OP clearly knew how to create the configuration as it was correct in the question. The issue was how to import that configuration so that it can be used. Creating another entity manager with the configuration how it was would have done nothing, except maybe cause more errors as the connection that it relied on would not exist.

Comment: Quotes may be needed to avoid a parse error: "The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar".

Answer (score 7):

You can declare the second driver that is specific to your bundle (named `SecondBundle` in your example using the `PrependExtensionInterface`.

Rename first your `config.yml` file in `SecondBundle` to `doctrine.yml` (or any other name that is not `config.yml`).

Change now your `SecondBundleExtension` class like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser as YamlParser;
// ...

class SecondBundleExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {    
        $yamlParser = new YamlParser();

        try {
            $doctrineConfig = $yamlParser->parse(
                file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/doctrine.yml')
            );
        } catch (ParseException $e) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The file "%s" does not contain valid YAML.', $file), 0, $e);
        }

        $container->prependExtensionConfig('doctrine', $doctrineConfig['doctrine']);
    }
}
```

Your `secondBundle` connection will now be automatically registered when you enable your bundle.

Comment: Your answer is much better than the selected answer. I used it! Something to note; You don't need to call $container->getExtensions(), nor do you need to use the line $doctrineExtension = $extensions['doctrine']. Great answer though

Comment: @Jaimz Thanks for the comments and glad it helped. I am going to remove the unused variables according to your comment :)